# Cannot hide keyboard on Android InputField

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keyboard

I am developing a chat app with Unity using uGUI. There is an InputField for the user to type in. The expected behaviour is

1. If the user presses OK or check mark button on the keyboard (I am using Google keyboard), send the message
2. If the user tap outside the keyboard, hide the keyboard

But both actions result to the same event which is End Edit. Is there anyway to differentiate these two actions?